# Convert EdmType to JsonSchemaType

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, code-generation, json.net, t4

I am making C# code generation with T4 for an ASP.NET Web API project... I need a simple way to convert an [EdmType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.data.metadata.edm.edmtype.aspx) to [JsonSchemaType](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema.htm).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since time flies, I ended up writing a switch, until I find a better solution...

```
public static class TypeMapper
{
    public static JsonSchemaType Convert(EdmType edmType)
    {
        switch (edmType.BuiltInTypeKind )
        {
            case BuiltInTypeKind.EnumType:
                return JsonSchemaType.String;

            case BuiltInTypeKind.ComplexType:
                return JsonSchemaType.Object;

            case BuiltInTypeKind.PrimitiveType:
                return GetPrimitiveType(edmType);

            default:
                return JsonSchemaType.Null;
        }
    }


    private static JsonSchemaType GetPrimitiveType(EdmType edmType)
    {
        switch (edmType.Name)
        {
            case "String":
            case "Guid":
            case "DateTime":
                return JsonSchemaType.String;

            case "Int32":
                return JsonSchemaType.Integer;

            case "Single":
            case "Double":
                return JsonSchemaType.Float;

            default:
                return JsonSchemaType.Null;
        }
    }
}
```